# Unnecessary try-finally

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

One lecture of [Design of Computer Program](https://www.udacity.com/course/design-of-computer-programs--cs212) on Udacity ask to implement a decorator to trace recursion:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

def decorator(d):
    "Make function d a decorator: d wraps a function fn."
    def _d(fn):
        return update_wrapper(d(fn), fn)
    update_wrapper(_d, d)
    return _d

@decorator
def trace(f):
    indent = '   '
    def _f(*args):
        signature = '%s(%s)' % (f.__name__, ', '.join(map(repr, args)))
        print '%s--> %s' % (trace.level*indent, signature)
        trace.level += 1
        try:
            # your code here
            print '%s<-- %s == %s' % ((trace.level-1)*indent, signature, result)
        finally:
            # your code here
        return # your code here
    trace.level = 0
    return _f

@trace
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

fib(4)
```

I fill the code into `trace` function and it works:

```
@decorator
def trace(f):
    indent = '   '
    def _f(*args):
        signature = '%s(%s)' % (f.__name__, ', '.join(map(repr, args)))
        print '%s--> %s' % (trace.level*indent, signature)
        trace.level += 1
        try:
            result = f(*args)
            print '%s<-- %s == %s' % ((trace.level-1)*indent, signature, result)
        finally:
            trace.level -= 1
        return result
    trace.level = 0
    return _f
```

Output:

```
--> fib(4)
   --> fib(3)
      --> fib(2)
         --> fib(1)
         <-- fib(1) == 1
         --> fib(0)
         <-- fib(0) == 1
      <-- fib(2) == 2
      --> fib(1)
      <-- fib(1) == 1
   <-- fib(3) == 3
   --> fib(2)
      --> fib(1)
      <-- fib(1) == 1
      --> fib(0)
      <-- fib(0) == 1
   <-- fib(2) == 2
<-- fib(4) == 5
```

But soon I find out that `trace` could go without `try-finally`:

```
@decorator
def trace(f):
    indent = '   '
    def _f(*args):
        signature = '%s(%s)' % (f.__name__, ', '.join(map(repr, args)))
        print '%s--> %s' % (trace.level*indent, signature)
        trace.level += 1
        result = f(*args)
        print '%s<-- %s == %s' % ((trace.level-1)*indent, signature, result)
        trace.level -= 1
        return result
    trace.level = 0
    return _f
```

With exactly the same output.

I don't see any point of `try-finally` in this case. Could some one explain to me?

Comment: Try to raise an exception in your `fib` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `fib` method and see the difference.

```
@trace
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        raise RuntimeError('Test')
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

"try-finally" makes sure that the code in the finally block is still executed during the stack unwinding caused by an exception.

**Edit**

In your case there is no need for it, but it is generally good practice.

**Edit** for @Rahn

```
try:
    result = f(*args)
    print '%s<-- %s == %s' % ((trace.level-1)*indent, signature, result)
finally:
    print '%s<-- %s == Exception' % ((trace.level-1)*indent, signature)
    trace.level -= 1
```

vs.

```
result = f(*args)
print '%s<-- %s == %s' % ((trace.level-1)*indent, signature, result)
trace.level -= 1
```

Comment: Your `fib` seems to produce same output within or without `try-finally`

Comment: The OP seems to know what `try..finally` does - he simply said he doesn't see any point in using that construct _in this case_. Frankly, neither do I.

Comment: @Rahn Visually, yes.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Except if you're writing general code (the `@trace` decorator presumably being designed to handle any number of functions), making it resilient in the face of exceptions, even if your initial use cases can't trigger exceptions, is always a good idea.